# Can keyboard input be obtained by using memory mapped registers instead of functions like scanf?

Tags: c, input, keyboard

I have these two questions concerning the memory mapped keyboard's register access:

1. Is it possible to read or write the status and data register of the keyboard that are
   memory mapped?
2. Where are these located in memory (in which address)?

I'm guessing that these memory locations won't be accessible by users, but I just wanted to make sure.

Comment: Most operating systems provide some lower-level keyboard apis (eg: directx on windows), and there's things like SDL that provide similar cross-platform apis. They're not "memory mapped keyboard register access" though -- that doesn't exist any more on any mainstream computing system (if it ever did).

Comment: This heavily depends on the system you are using. You can have all kinds of hardware that receives keyboard input, ranging from PCs with dedicated I/O ports, to home computers that scan the keyboard hardware in software. Please [edit] your question to tell us about the target system. Also depending on the OS of that system your program would need super-user rights.